# Float right not working correctly

Tags: html, css

On my [website](http://wowsk.org) I have a comments section on the far right side of the screen. I would like the comment to be inline with the right side of the comments section. I figured float right would do it, and it does, to an extent. As you can see it could go another few pixels so it was inline. My CSS for it looks like this:

```
        #addCommentButton{
            float:right;
        }
```

and HTML is this:

```
<div id="comment_container">
        <form id="comment_form">
            <input class="input line1" id="nameInput" placeholder="Name">
            <button id="addCommentButton" class="line1" type="submit">Comment</button>
            <textarea class="input" id="comment_area" placeholder="Comment here"></textarea>
        </form>
        <div id="comments"><span id="loading">Loading comments...</span></div>
</div>
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I have never had it occur before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, do this:

```
.comment, #comment_area, #comment_form {
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Calculated width of that area is bigger few pixels than declared...

> With box-sizing: border-box;, we can change the box model to what was
>   once the "quirky" way, where an element's specified width and height
>   aren't affected by padding or borders.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 1):

Try to set padding on form to `0px`

```
form#comment_form {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Your button is positioned correctly as I can see but form's padding is pushing it to left for few pixels.

Comment: I guess we just did it the exact opposite of each other :)

Comment: I couldn't get this way to work but nevermind's answer worked fine. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

This will work. change your text area width to 294px; to compensate for the left and right 2px padding and the 1px margin.

```
<textarea class="input" id="comment_area" placeholder="Comment here" tabindex="2" style="width: 294px;"></textarea>
```